# Reset pruned trials in Optuna study?

Tags: python, optuna

If I have a study where all the pruned trials needs to be reset for some reason, is there a way to do this?

Maybe something that might work: Creating a copy of the current study where pruned trials have their state reset.

Thank you for any suggestions to reset all pruned trials

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can re-evaluate the objective function using the parameters of the pruned trials.

For example, if you have a study named `'example-study'` and an SQLite file `example.db` you can:

```
import optuna
study = optuna.create_study(study_name='example-study', storage='sqlite:///example.db', load_if_exists=True)
for trial in study.trials:
    if trial.state == optuna.trial.TrialState.PRUNED: 
        study.enqueue_trial(trial.params)
study.optimize(objective)
```